# Should I define variables in short blocks/functions of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I know defining variables is helpful when you have a big block. But in short blocks/functions, where the variable is used once only, it seems just a waste of bytes. Here's an [example](http://help.dottoro.com/ljwbxutr.php). Isn't it better to do this:

```
function SelectInput() {
            document.getElementById("input").select();
```

rather than this:

```
 function SelectInput () {
            var input = document.getElementById ("input");
            input.select ();
        }
```

Comment: What is the question here exactly..

Comment: Isn't it better to avoid defining variables in small functions?

Comment: The question is, what is your goal. Do you want to have a nice, readable code, or do you need it short (for some reason) and dirty?

Comment: A nice, readable code that is as short as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a variable whenever there is an expression that would unnecessarily be evaluated multiple times. You also can use variables that increase readability by being named descriptively, and breaking large chains into reasonable chunks.

It does not matter how large the block is.

In your case the variable `input` is pretty useless, it's obvious that `document.getElementById("input")` returns an/the input.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case, as you say, it's a waste of time and bytes. However, there are short blocks where using variables can be helpful:

```
function changeStyle() {
    var style = document.getElementById('image').style; //an extra variable here would help us check whether there is an element with id 'image' or not.
    style.width = 200;
    style.height = 100;
}
```

Even in three lines of code, defining `style` is useful, because accesing the DOM is slow compared to create one simple variable. Here, as I note in the comment, you should create a variable to store the results of the getElementById() method, as it can return null.

Comment: Yes, by short blocks/functions I mean the ones in which the variable is used once only -- like the one above.

Comment: In that case, it would depend on how sure you are about the existence of the element. If `getElementById(id)` is null, a exception would be thrown.