# Reason to declare variable if it's going to be used only once

Tags: javascript

What is the point of declaring variable if that variable is going to be used only once?
Take a look at those two functions. Is there a difference? Which one is better and why?

```
function showtext(){
var elem = document.getElementById("elemid");
var txt1 = '<p>Some random text</p>';
elem.innerHTML = txt1;
}
```

or

```
function showtext(){
document.getElementById("elemid").innerHTML = '<p>Some random text</p>';
}
```

Comment: Given that code, there's no point. But if you want to make sure `elem` isn't `null`, then it would make more sense for that variable, but still not for the `txt1`.

Comment: There isn't... UNLESS `#elemid` doesn't exist and you get an error (which you could test for, or use a `try/catch`). Or what @cookiemonster said.

Comment: also the first option will probably look better in a tutorial, especially if you add a couple comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I define variables in short blocks/functions of JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22249069/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason for using variables in such a case is better readable code (spread over multiple lines instead of a single too-long one), especially if you use *descriptive* variable names for your declarations.

In this particular case (except we're dealing with absolute beginners) nothing is gained, as `getElementById` obviously returns an `elem`ent, and `txt1` means nothing.

Comment: As others commented, `getElementById` could also return null.

Comment: Sure, but the code doesn't expect it so why should the variable name? :-)

Comment: My comment is not directed at the code snippets, but rather at their author ;-)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is function scoped, so all variables get cleaned up once you leave the function.

To me, declaring separate variables for each thing makes sense to keep the code legible. The point of using variables in any programming language is to name and describe things.

So instead of:

```
function showtext(){
    var unimaginativeName1 = document.getElementById("elemid");
    var unimaginativeName2 = '<p>Some random text</p>';
    unimaginativeName1.innerHTML = unimaginativeName2;
}
```

You can tell a better story with:

```
function showtext(){
    var elemDescription = document.getElementById("elemid");
    var elemTxt = '<p>Some random text</p>';
    elemDescription.innerHTML = elemTxt;
}
```

It would read better than this.

```
document.getElementById("elemid").innerHTML = '<p>Some random text</p>';
```