# Function call as parameter value?

Tags: javascript, performance

```
function fn1() {
   return "hello worl!";
}

function fn2(data) {
   console.log(data)
}

fn2(fn1())

// Calling fn2 function passing(same time calling) fn1 function as an argument.
```

Is this correct approach? or is there any other method? Please assist me.

I have read some articles about passing function value to argument without the parentheses.

(or)

Shall I do like this?

```
var f = fn1()
fn2(f)
```

Comment: Whether it's correct depends on how it's intended to be used. Your code example is correct, but it would be just as correct to do `fn2("foo")`. The `fn2()` doesn't care where its argument comes from. In your case it's coming from the return value of the `fn1()` invocation. The `fn1` function itself is not being passed.

Comment: It's a matter of preference, but generally, it's better to avoid a temporary variable.

Comment: Yes. you can do that. You don't have to define a variable just to pass a value returned by a function - it's up to you and your coding standards and maintainability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a function call as a parameter value. You can either pass *a function*:

```
fn2(fn1); // logs `function fn1() {…}`
```

or the *the result of a function call*:

```
fn2(fn1()); // logs `Hello worl!`
```

Whether you use an extra variable to intermediately store that result value [doesn't really matter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25961806/1048572) when it's used only once.

> I have read some articles about passing function value to argument without the parentheses.

Yes, that happens some times, for example when you pass handler functions to `addEventListener` or so. There you don't want to call the function, but pass *the function as a value* - and it's makes an important difference.

In your case, when you want to pass the `hello worl!`-string to your logging function, this is not appropriate. You want to call the `fn1()` function.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If the value returned by `fn1()` where to be used multiple times, then it wouldn't be a bad idea to call it once doing `var f = fn1()`. For example if it was the length or an array, distance, etc, that you would use multiple times. So:

```
var f = fn1();
fn2(f);
fn3(f);
fn4(f);
...
```

But again, the performence is likely to be very slight, unless `fn1()` was computationally heavy. Although it it's just useing `f` once, then there is not much of a need to store it in a variable:

```
fn2(fn1());
```

Comment: Yeah, Thank you @Spencer Wieczorek... you're right, I thought some times it may give error in Chrome like "Max call size exceeded" if we call this in multiple places fn2(fn1())